# Blocking sockets v/s non-blocking sockets in multi-threaded single server multiple client application

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winapi, network-programming

I had been working on a Server Client aplication where Server is going to service(sendto + receivefrom)'x' number of Clients at a time. For this purpose, I have created 'x' number of threads on Server side so that each thread is dadicated to one single client. Inside each thread there is a specific socket for just for its client. I was thinking to make these sockets non-blocking but now I think using blocking socket inside each thread is a better idea. Blocking Socket continuously waits to receive data and whenever there is a need to send anything, sendto() is called. Is using blocking Socket in such a situation a good approach or should I use non-blocking sockets?
Waiting for help!!!

Comment: If you have a dedicated thread for each connection, it's not really needed to make the sockets non-blocking. On the other hand you should be careful not to have to many connections, as too many threads may severely degrade system performance (CPU is doing more work swapping between threads than doing "real" work).

Comment: If your design is 1 thread/socket, and the thread's basic purpose is to service network reqeuests ... then blocking is *definitely* the best approach.  IMHO...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Thank you so much for the reply but I have a little confusion here. What if my Socket is blocking in call to recvfrom() and waiting to receive some data from the client and at the same time, the Server want to send some data?

Comment: @paulsm4 : Thank you for the help but in what sense blocking is better approach than non-\blocking?

Comment: If you want to asynchronously be able to send data while waiting for data to be received at the same time, then no, you can't use blocking sockets. And if you start doing e.g. `select` polling it's really no use to do it on a single connection in a single thread at the time, then it's better to pull more connections into a single thread and have less threads.

Comment: Non-blocking sockets are only useful if you want one thread to service multiple connections. Using non-blocking sockets and a poll/select loop means that your thread does not sit idle while waiting for new connections.

Comment: The main blocking socket problem is that `recv` function doesn't return until some data is received. However, this is solved by closing the socket from another thread - `recv` immediately returns with failure. Sometimes I use blocking sockets because they have simple programming interface.

Comment: and what if I set RECV_TIMEOUT and cause my recvfrom() funtion not to be blocking infinietly? In that case I think I can use blocking sockets efficiently

Comment: You can also use the flag `MSG_PEEK` with your `recvfrom` call, to see if there is any data available to receive. Or, on supported platforms, the `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : +1 for the positive addition :)

Comment: In general: "Blocking is Good.  Polling is Evil."  "select()" does this for you on *nix; allowing you to multiplex different inputs on a single thread.  The Winsock asynch API calls do the same for you on Windows - your program doesn't need to do anything until you get a message on the main event loop.  But if you've already got threads processing your socket I/O ... then asynch multiplexing is just extra overhead.  With 1 thread/1 socket, the simplest ... and best performing ... approach is to use blocking socket I/O.  IMHO...

Comment: There's no reason to have a thread per client if you're not going to use blocking IO.  Really, I'd recommend using a single process (at least for the IO portion), and non-blocking IO.  It's much more efficient, and a TON simpler to get correct.  Threads are just asking for trouble, especiailly if there is a lot of interaction.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Don't use MSG_PEEK for anything.  Ever.  Either select()/poll() for data or use non-blocking, but never require a read to succeed immediately if it would cause your program to block in a bad way if the read blocked.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "If you want to asynchronously be able to send data while waiting for data to be received at the same time, then no, you can't use blocking sockets.". This is blatantly untrue.

Comment: @EJP : Can you explain little further> According to my understanding, if I am waiting for data to b e received on a blocking socket, I can not send data at the same time at that blocking socket. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AyeshaHassan Yes, you are wrong. TCP connections and sockets are full-duplex. You can send and receive at the same time.

Comment: @EJP : and what about UDP?

Comment: @EJP I meant that the same thread can't call `send` or `recv` as it might block the thread thereby making it impossible to call the other function (`recv` or `send`) from the same thread.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I agree

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking to make these sockets non-blocking but now I think using blocking socket inside each thread is a better idea. Blocking Socket continuously waits to receive data and whenever there is a need to send anything, sendto() is called. Is using blocking Socket in such a situation a good approach or should I use non-blocking sockets?

I agree. Unless you are expecting hundreds of thousands of connections, I don't see a reason to go beyond threads and blocking I/O. `select()` and friends were designed in the days when the alternative to blocking I/O was another *process,* not another thread.